# Function not creating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have created a simple function for cleaning dataframe, but it is not creating it. Why?

The data frame that I would like to have is df_cleaned when I run the function.

```
def cleaning_data(data_set):
    df_cleaned = []
    for index in data_set.columns[4:]:    
        data_set['new'] = 1    
        df_clean_all = pd.DataFrame(data_set['new'])     
        df_clean_all[index] = data_set[index][data_set[index].between(data_set[index].quantile(0.05),  
        data_set[index].quantile(0.95))]     
        
        df_clean_all = df_clean_all.drop('new',  1)
        df_clean_all = df_clean_all.fillna(df_clean_all.mean())   
        df_cleaned.append(df_clean_all)     
        
    df_cleaned = pd.concat(df_cleaned, axis = 1)

cleaning_data(df_data)
```

Comment: `return df_cleaned`?

Comment: and set the result to a variable: `df = cleaning_data(df_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that a matter of returning your result?  `return df_cleaned`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def cleaning_data(data_set):
    df_cleaned = []
    for index in data_set.columns[4:]:    
        data_set['new'] = 1    
        df_clean_all = pd.DataFrame(data_set['new'])     
        df_clean_all[index] = data_set[index][data_set[index].between(data_set[index].quantile(0.05),  
        data_set[index].quantile(0.95))]     
        
        df_clean_all = df_clean_all.drop('new',  1)
        df_clean_all = df_clean_all.fillna(df_clean_all.mean())   
        df_cleaned.append(df_clean_all)     
        
    return pd.concat(df_cleaned, axis = 1)

random_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(10, 6)), columns=list('ABCDEF')
)
print(cleaning_data(random_df))
```